# Javascript or JQuery to remove certain text and characters between

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have HTML like so:

```
<br>
For the application these are [a bunch of random characters that need to be removed]).
<br?
<br>
```

I need to use Javascript/JQuery (probably a regular expression) to remove the HTML starting with:

```
 For the application these are
```

and ending with:

```
).
<br>
<br>
```

Everything in between must go too.

Comment: Do you need to be specifically targeting that sentence, or would it be okay to remove any text from the container holding that content?

Comment: document.body.innerHTML = '<br>\r\n';
Not too sure what you're asking, but that should leave you with just the first <br> on the page since everything else must be removed.

Comment: That sentence needs to be targeted. That should be the starting point of the regular express and then the ending point above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a snippet to remove everything from and including `For` to `).` using regex.

```js
document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(/For(.*?)\)\./,'');

console.log(document.body.innerHTML);
```

```html
<br>
For the application these are (sdi12ni3jo45n).
<br>
<br>
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood, this should work for you. Demo url: http://regexr.com/3gioj

```
$(your_element).replace(/For the application these are .+?(\)\.)/g,"")
```

Answer (score 0):

If the words and characters are accurate and 100% exact in all scenarios, then easily:

```
var sentence = "For the application these are foofoofoo!!!)"

sentence = sentence.replace(sentence.split("For the application these are ")[1].split(")")[0], "");

console.log(sentence);

//output: For the application these are )
```

Don't even need RegEx. Then just append sentence to wherever u want to

Comment: This does not answer OP's question. Note: "Everything in between must go too."

Comment: I don't grammatically get  "Everything in between must go too."

Comment: In other words, "`For`" and "`).`", and all characters in between them, should be removed from the page.